# Как делать такого рода аккордионы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том, что как это позиционировать вообще, с помощью `SVG` делать такие блоки - не вариант, т.к. тогда текст нельзя менять в случаи чего (Вернее очень трудно). Если фоном делать, то как сделать анимацию открытия данных блоков?

Дальше еще вопрос, там где 'hovered' нужно сделать как-то так что бы подсвечивалось и линия, и этот косой блок. Приходится рисовать с помощью `SVG`, но как тогда сделать это адаптивным.

У меня нет на данный момент даже идей, как сделать это нормально, что бы все не на костылях держалось, может есть уже готовые примеры, что бы посмотреть как там такое реализовано?

Comment: Одно открываете, остальное скрываете, в чем сложность то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".items").accordion({
    collapsible: true
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

body {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.items {
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

h3 {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  border-left:none;
}

.items h3 span {
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  float: left;
}

.items h3:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  background: lightblue;
  transform: skew(20deg);
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.items div {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="items">
  <h3><span>Section 1</span></h3>
  <div>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum
      a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
  </div>
  <h3><span>Section lorem ipsum 2</span></h3>
  <div>
    <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
  </div>
  <h3><span>Section itemes 3</span></h3>
  <div>
    <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam
      nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3><span>section propper cordid feriums 4</span> </h3>
  <div>
    <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est. </p>
    <p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```